# How to make IKImageBrowserView Quick Look icons look like Finder icons?

Tags: macos, cocoa, quicklook, ikimagebrowserview

[IKImageBrowserView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004708) provides a multi-image view much like Finder (in fact, a class-dump shows that Finder uses it internally). And there's a constant `IKImageBrowserQuickLookPathRepresentationType` which allows you to provide paths or URLs to the browser view, which it displays as Quick Look previews.

However, these previews aren't like the "icon"-style previews that Finder displays:
[image: Finder style]

But rather a larger preview:
[image: plain preview]

Is there a way to make IKImageBrowserView use the icon preview style, with the curled document corner and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public way to do that directly (using `IKImageBrowserQuickLookPathRepresentationType`) so you will have to produce the image yourself using QLThumbnail API (`kQLThumbnailOptionIconModeKey`) and feed that to the `IKImageBrowserView`.